# Axes for bivariate normal distribution with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I got the following figure:

[image]

with this code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\centerx{2}
\def\centery{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:6,domain y=-5:3] 
        {exp(-( (x-\centerx)^2 + (y-\centery)^2)/3 )};
    \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=blue,pin=90:$\mu$] 
        at (axis cs:\centerx,\centery,1) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I wonder how to get this figure without some axes as below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `axis lines` options (see section 4.9.9 of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\centerx{2}
\def\centery{-1}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=left]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:6,domain y=-5:3] 
        {exp(-( (x-\centerx)^2 + (y-\centery)^2)/3 )};
    \node[circle,inner sep=1pt,fill=blue,pin=90:$\mu$] 
        at (axis cs:\centerx,\centery,1) {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bivariate plot with only left axis lines]

Comment: Thanks @hugovdberg for your answer. If you have noticed it the pfd has value greater than 1 which is not possible. Have you any idea? Please also include figure in your answer. Thanks

Comment: I added a picture to my original answer. The maximum value does not exceed 1, it only looks like it does because of the angle at which you see the picture. This optical illusion is just an artefact of your request. You could add the option `view={0}{0}` to the axis options to move the camera such that you look straight to the side, and you will see it is perfectly fine.